# Difference between Distribution board main switch and mains

Tags: electrical-panel

What is the difference between a distribution board/distribution box, main switch, and mains? Are they all the same or are they difference from each other?

Comment: Are you asking about a location that has multiple occupancys? Up to 6 disconnects? Going to a panel board at each residence?

Comment: Iam asking the general meanings of the terms since i cannot find proper descriptions on the net

Comment: They're slang terms. They don't have strict proper meanings.  They might have meaning inside the context of a conversation.  "Distribution board" might have a meaning in some countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Distribution box** (aka distribution board, breaker panel, electric panel, breakerboard) is the the enclosure where the main power feed comes in and is distributed to individual circuits
- **Main switch** is the master switch that shuts off all power, and is the first thing the power runs to that comes into the panel.
- **"Mains"** (aka mains voltage) refers to main line-level voltage (generally 120V or 240V, depending on where you live) and is used to refer to things connected to the electrical system and thus subject to code. It's often used to distinguish from something that is "low voltage" <sup>1</sup> (eg, 12 or 24V circuits)

[image]
[image]

<sup>**1**</sup> Note, technically this is called ["extra-low voltage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_voltage), and is anything <50V AC or <120V DC. "High voltage" is anything >1000V AC, and "low voltage" is everything in between, but really only linesmen that work for the power company call it that. In a house or commercial situation, you basically never see anything higher than 240V so we just use the terms "mains" or "low voltage".